# No se puede usar un objeto de tipo stdClass como matriz

Tags: laravel

estoy trbajando con laravel , recojo los datos mediante una consulta y de esa consulta que se ejecuta correctamente según criterios que paso, quiero recorrer ese objeto, y almacenarlos en otras tabla.

uso use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB

Mi codigo :

```
   $array_tankDetails = DB::table('tanks')->where( ['estado'=>'Activo','area_id'=>$area])->get();
             //ésta variable almacena lo que necesito   
                    foreach ($array_tankDetails as $tankDetails){
                        $tankDetails=  TankDetail::create([
                            'production_id'   => $tabla_id,
                            'tank_id'     => $tankDetails['tank_id'],
                            'fecha' =>$fecha,                            
                            'altura'   => 0,
                            'agua'   =>0,
                            'vol_agua'   => 0,
                            'vol_oil'   => 0,
                            'vol_total'   => 0,
                            'create_at' => now(),
  
                        ]);
```

Mi resultado se observa claramente el resultado

[image: se observan los objatos con sus valores]

Comment: El array estaría en una clave llamada `items`, prueba así: `foreach ($array_tankDetails->items as $tankDetails){`

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta... ¿que error tienes?  No se verlo, perdona, ni tampoco entiendo que pretendes... Si necesitas usar un objeto en PHP como un array mira a ver si lo puedes recorrer mediante `(array) $objeto` para que lo pase a array.

Comment: @a-cenano quiero por ejempo de eso objeto que obtengo recorrerlo y almacenar en otra tablas el id, cte, api

Comment: @OcielGarrido Pues hazlo, ambas soluciones que hemos dado en los comentarios son válidas para recorrer el objeto o para tratarlo como un array, ahora debes ponerlas en practica y usar la que más te convenga. En mi comentario te puse la forma de convertir un objeto a array, tan solo debes asignarlo a una variable y tratarla como un array para lo que necesites, pero eso debes hacerlo tu, y si te surgen nuevos problemas lo comentas y te ayudamos.

Comment: disculpas @a-cedano  ´ foreach ($array_tankDetails->item as $tankDetails){
    $tankDetails=  TankDetail::create([
         'production_id'   => $tabla_id,
         'tank_id'     => $tankDetails['tank_id'],
                                                    
             ....             ,
                       ......
                            'create_at' => now(),  
                        ]); `
                    }

Comment: Resuelto!!! muchas gracias a ambos

Comment: Tienes que ver la estructura de los objetos. En la imagen que compartes dice: `#items: array:6`  significa entonces que ese array tiene 6 elementos, y que **se encuentra en una clave que se llama `items`**. Si tú no accedes a esa clave, no estarás accediendo al array. Ese es el *quid* de la cuestión. Todo lo demás es **secundario**. Y es que lo que haces en tu bucle puede ser marear más los datos. ¿Por qué los sacas de un sitio para meterlos en otro? No entiendo ese proceder. Lo propio ahí sería o mostrar los datos, o si los necesitas en otro contenedor, mapearlos a ese contenedor...